# Why all my https request are consider in server log as POST?

Tags: java, post, https, get

Why all my request methods (post,get,delete) are considered as POST method? if something wrong in the code can you explain what is the problem and how to fix it?

the method has a string parameter where I change it to post/delete/get 
for all request I got https error code 405 but for post I got 200.

Thank you

[my code -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8OwP.png)

Comment: first of all, please avoid posting screenshots of your code, instead, post them in your question in code format, second of all, what's your `method` variable set to that's used in `connection.setMethod(method)`, that's what's determining the http request method.

Comment: I know, I'm calling that method 3 times with "POST" and "GET" and "DELETE" , it a string hold the type of the method

Answer (score 1):

well, Http-Code `405` means: `Method Not Allowed` => your server only implemented a `POST` method. Until you implement another methods **on the server** you will not be able to call them from your client.

Comment: in my server I have implemented 3 methods they are tested using curl command - works perfectly fine, I want now to use Java I think the logic of using one method to do post-get-delete is not correct - I believe there are different parameters that are not needed for post but needed for get or delete

Comment: No, if you get 405, then your problem is on the server-side. You can easily test it in your browser, just put the url in a browser-tab and see what you get. Browser will automatically send a `GET` request

Comment: wait a second maybe your problem is that you write a body for a `GET` and `DLETE` request, `GET` and `DELETE` requests shouldn't contain a body. Try to remove it from your code

Comment: It works from browser with get/post/delete - it works without the body but I need to pass the username-password , how I can do that ?

Comment: well for `GET` and `DELETE` you need to pass the parameters in the url itself, like: `https://www.example.com/test?username=demo&password=demo` but keep in mind, that you will see the username and password in clear text in your logs. You should only send your credentials using a `POST` request

Comment: I don't want this solution, I'm using https to avoid this. I will see if I can find  a way ! thanks

Comment: well to avoid this you should use some kind of access token. You should authenticate once to get the token and use it for further requests. Depending on your server you could simply use a session to identify the user

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this, since POST method required the body while GET and DELETE do not need the body, for Authentication I used basicauth.

```
        if (user_name != "" || password != "")
            {
                if (method == "POST")
                {
                    // write body to query
                    String body = "username=" + user_name + "&password=" + password;
                    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(body);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    String userpass = user_name + ":" + password;
                    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
                    connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
                    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

                }

           }
            // connect
            connection.connect();
            //results
            String results = request_call_results(connection);
            JSONObject json = String_toJson(results);
            return json;
```